# How to access length of an array in a json object using javascript in asp.net mvc view

Tags: javascript, c#, model-view-controller, certificate

I want to access the length of an array in a json object with javascript. I am parsing the List Model of my View in a JSON object and try to access it.
Here is my function:

```
<script>
    function showCerts(storeName) {
        var store = storeName;
        var model = '@Html.Raw(Json.Encode(Model))';
        var obj = JSON.parse(model);
        for (var i = 0; i < Object.keys(obj[store].Certificates).length; i++) {
            var node = document.createElement("p");
            var textNode = document.createTextNode(obj[store].Certificates[i].FingerPrint);
            node.appendChild(textNode);
            document.getElementById("certs").appendChild(node);
        }
    }
</script>
```

The JSON object looks like this:

```
[{"Name":"ClientAuthIssuer","ServerName":"servername","Certificates":[
{"id" = 0, "Name" = "CertName"}, 
{"id" = 1, "Name" = "CertName"}, 
{"id" = 2, "Name" = "CertName"}]},
{"Name":"Disallowed","ServerName":"servername","Certificates":[
{"id" = 0, "Name" = "CertName"}, 
{"id" = 1, "Name" = "CertName"}, 
{"id" = 2, "Name" = "CertName"}]},
{"Name":"MY","ServerName":"servername","Certificates":[
{"id" = 0, "Name" = "CertName"}, 
{"id" = 1, "Name" = "CertName"}, 
{"id" = 2, "Name" = "CertName"}]}
]
```

I want to get the length of the Certificates property of ClientAuthIssuer for example to iterate through the certificates in it and add it to a div as a p element.

I always get this error when trying to run my script:

```
Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read property 'Certificates' of undefined
```

Thank you for your help.

Comment: So what is value of `storeName` when this error occurs? You shouldn't need to use Object.keys() to iterate through an array either

Comment: I have a button called "ClientAuthIssuer" which calls the javascript function and also pass the parameter "ClientAuthIssuer" to the function as storename.

Answer (score 0):

This error message clearly I dictate your obj[store] is undefined.